# Why am I getting a "the page isn't redirecting properly" error?

Tags: php, facebook

I got this from nettuts, can someone please tell me why am I getting a "the page isn't redirecting properly" error?

```
<?php
# We require the library
require("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID_HERE',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE',
    'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getUser();

if(!empty($session)) {
    # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
    try{
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();

        # req_perms is a comma separated list of the permissions needed
        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'
        ));
        header("Location: $url");
    } catch (Exception $e){}
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

Comment: If an exception occurs, do something with it. *Never* just throw it away.

Answer (score 4):

You redirect authenticated user to `$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(...))`, creating a redirect loop.

You should redirect only unauthenticated users (redirect with `req_perms` should be in `else` clause). The redirect in `try` should happen only if you detect that user hasn't granted you all required permissions.

You can check granted permissions by invoking:

```
$perms = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos FROM permissions WHERE uid=' . $facebook->getUser()
));
```

---

Modified code:

```
<?php
# We require the library
require("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID_HERE',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE',
    'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getUser();

if(empty($session)) {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'
    ));
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
// user is logged in
```

Comment: can you give help me fix that code i pasted above ? :( , i don't understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest PHP SDK, several changes have been made and the permissions you are asking do not work that way.

Here is an updated code.

```
<?php 
# We require the library 
require("facebook.php"); 

# Creating the facebook object 
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID_HERE', 
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE', 
    'cookie' => true 
)); 

# Let's see if we have an active session 
$session = $facebook->getUser(); 

if(empty($session)) { 
    # There's no active session, let's generate one 
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 
        "response_type"=>"token", //Can also be "code" if you need to
        "scope" => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos' ,
        "redirect_uri"=> "http://test.com" //Your app callback url
    )); 
    header("Location: $url"); 
    exit; 
} 
// user is logged in
```

More info: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/